# Google Charts & SharePoint List: Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined

Tags: google-chart

I created a function to create multiple piecharts of a SharePoint list column:

```
var countOrbit = {};
var OrbitName = 'Orbit';

...

google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAllCharts(countOrbit, OrbitName));

    function drawAllCharts(countChoices, name) {
        var rows = [];
        for (var property in countChoices) {
            if (countChoices.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                rows.push([property, countChoices[property]]);
            }
        }


        var datatable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        datatable.addColumn('string', 'Type');
        datatable.addColumn('number', 'Quantity');
        datatable.addRows(rows);
        var options = {
            title: String(name),
            is3D: 'true'
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById(String(name)+'Chart'));
        chart.draw(datatable, options);
    }

...


  <body>
        <div id="OrbitChart" style="width:700px;height:500px;"></div>
  </body>
```

But I get this error:

```
Statistics.aspx:689 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'DataTable' of undefined
    at drawAllCharts (Statistics.aspx:689)
    at Object.success (Statistics.aspx:676)
```

Answer (score 1):

This helped me:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/sk39mXZZ15U

I used

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function(){drawAllCharts(countOrbit, 'Orbit')});
```

instead of

```
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAllCharts(countOrbit, OrbitName));
```